# How to find the limit? I can't use integration either. First I thought it would be infinity but from the test of divergence it converges.

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^2 }{n^3 +n^2 +k}$$ I tried to use Riemann sum but I can't find a suitable form.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{k^2}{(n+1)n^2} \ge \frac{k^2}{n^3+n^2+k} \ge \frac{k^2}{(n+2)n^2}$

Comment: Thanks! Now the squeeze th works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2}{n^3+n^2+1}\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^2}{n^3+n^2+k}\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2}{n^3+n^2+n}$$
Therefore, limit is $\dfrac13$ by sandwich theorem.